# Symfony's routing components(or my misuse) choking my app

Tags: php, symfony, http, routes, benchmarking

Few days ago I asked a question how could I make my own argument resolver for my own php framework, I understood how thanks to the answer, but time did not allow me to create it so I decided to roll with Symfony's :

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection
Symfony\Component\Routing\Route
Symfony\Component\Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher
Symfony\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel
```

If Silex, Drupal and Laravel could use them, why not me?

Well I implemented them and created a new route let's call it /testroute(TestController::IndexAction), so far it's OK.
I ran tests with apache's ab for my index route '/' : 1000 requests for 10 concurrent users and it resulted in 3400 requests per second.

But Then I tested my new route and the results was .... 9 requests per second, yup nine.

I can't shake of the feeling that it is somehow my fault, but I am open to suggestions, here is the code for my framework :

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /framework/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front.php [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html front.php
```

front.php (my front controller)

require 'config/configuration.php';

```
require 'autoloader.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;

use core\Kernel\AppKernel;


$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$routes = include 'config/routing.php';

$context = new RequestContext();
$context->fromRequest($request);

//App kernel created by me
$appKern = new AppKernel($request, $routes, $context);

$appKern->run();
```

routing.php (all of the routes)

```
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Route;

$routes = new RouteCollection();

$routes->add('index', new Route('/', array('_controller' => 'app\Controllers\IndexController::indexAction')));
$routes->add('profiles', new Route('/profiles', array('_controller' => 'app\Controllers\ProfilesController::indexAction')));


return $routes;
```

AppKernel.php

namespace core\Kernel;

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel;
use Symfony\Component\Routing;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCollection;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RequestContext;

class AppKernel {

    private $request;

    private $routes;

    private $context;


    public function __construct(Request $request, RouteCollection $routes, RequestContext $context) {

        $this->request = $request;
        $this->routes = $routes;
        $this->context = $context;
    }

    private function callController($controller, $arguments) {

        $response = call_user_func_array($controller, $arguments);
    }

    public function run() {

        $matcher = new Routing\Matcher\UrlMatcher($this->routes, $this->context);
        $resolver = new HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver();

        try {
            $this->request->attributes->add($matcher->match($this->request->getPathInfo()));

            $controller = $resolver->getController($this->request);
            $arguments = $resolver->getArguments($this->request, $controller);

            $this->callController($controller, $arguments);
        } catch (Routing\Exception\ResourceNotFoundException $e) {
            $response = new Response('Not Found', 404);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $response = new Response('An error occurred', 500);
        }
    }

}
```

autoloader.php

```
require_once 'Symfony/Component/ClassLoader/ClassLoader.php';

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassLoader;

$loader = new ClassLoader();

// to enable searching the include path (eg. for PEAR packages)
$loader->setUseIncludePath(true);

// ... register namespaces and prefixes here - see below

$loader->register();

$loader->addPrefix('Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation', 'Symfony/Components/http-foundation');
$loader->addPrefix('app\Controllers', ROOT . 'app/Controllers');
$loader->addPrefix('core\Db', ROOT . 'core/Db');
$loader->addPrefix('core\Kernel', ROOT . 'core/Kernel');
$loader->addPrefix('Symfony\Component\Routing', 'Symfony/Component/Routing');
$loader->addPrefix('Symfony\Component\HttpKernel', 'Symfony/Component/HttpKernel');
```

Both of my controllers are empty, I don't believe that the problem is with them.

P.S. I am following Potencier's how to create your own framework

Comment: It may sound stupid but have you tried to change the routes order? I mean, add `/profiles` first.

Comment: I just did, nothing has changed

Comment: Can you just visit the URL in a browser and give us the response you get?